# Using SQL Server 2012 Standard with Bitlocker

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We're trying to use Bitlocker to secure an SQL Server 2012 database. We don't have any issue getting bitlocker to work... the issue we have is that once the drive is locked, SQL Server can no longer read the data.

We'd love to use TDE, obviously, but since that's limited to the Enterprise edition, that's a no-go. We have TPM activated on the server. This is in a Windows Domain and we use Windows Authentication... but once the drive is encrypted, we cannot access the DB with anything.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the account that the SQL Server runs as to enable Bitlocker.

Comment: Oh - so the Domain account we use for SQL Server itself must be the account used to turn on Bitlocker? Does the C:\ drive also need to have bitlocker enabled (since that's where the SQL Server runs)?

Comment: Yes, the SQL Account needs to enable bitlocker.  No you don't need to bitlocker the C drive unless you have another reason to.

Comment: Okay - we'll try that today and I'll report back.

Comment: That was exactly it. I will say that you really DO want to turn Bitlocker on for your system drive as well. Otherwise you have to manually unlock the drive every time you restart the system. (The auto-unlock feature requires the system drive to be bitlocked)